# Return the 90th percentile values in R

Tags: r, percentile

For example, I have a dataset of 30-years air temperature of a city, the dataset looks like:

```
Year  Julian_date  temperature
1991    1             2.1
1991    2             2.2
...     ...           ...
1991    365           2.3
1992    1             2.1
...     ...           ...
1992    365           2.5
...     ...           ...
2020    366           2.5
```

I would like to calculate the 90th percentile value of each Julian date (from different years), and returen the results, like:

```
Julian_date        value(the 90th percentile)
1                  2.4
2                  2.6
...                ...
365                2.5
```

How should I write the code in r?

Comment: There's an exactly the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72157696/create-new-dataframe-of-summary-90th-percentile-statistics-for-multiple-rows-o/72157813#72157813) a few hours ago

Comment: Maybe something like `df %>% group_by(Julian_date) %>% summarize(value = quantile(temperature, probs = 0.9))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first group by `Julian_date`, then use the `quantile` function to set the probability inside `summarise`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Julian_date) %>% 
  summarise("value (the 90th percentile)" = quantile(temperature, probs=0.9, na.rm=TRUE))
```

**Output**

```
  Julian_date `value (the 90th percentile)`
        <int>                         <dbl>
1           1                           2.1
2           2                           2.2
3         365                           2.5
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 1992L, 1992L, 2020L
), Julian_date = c(1L, 2L, 365L, 1L, 365L, 365L), temperature = c(2.1, 
2.2, 2.3, 2.1, 2.5, 2.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Dear Andrew, thank you for your answer! I run your code, the output shows only one row and one colume: ```value(the 90th percentile) <dbl> 2.5```; Do you know maybe where I do wrong?

Comment: @Jellz Are you sure that you have the `group_by(Julian_date)` in the pipe? If not, then it would only return one row and one column.

Comment: I restarted R, It works now...

Comment: @Jellz Okay, good! Probably just one of those weird glitches that happens every once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `quantile()` function. If `(from different years)` in your question means  each year should have separate calculation, then you need to group the data frame by `Year` and `Julian_date`. If instead it means the different years are combined, you need to group the data frame only by `Julian_date`, as @AndrewGB and @benson23 showed.

```
library(dplyr)
yourdf %>% group_by(Year, Julian_date) %>% 
summarise (value_90th_percentile = quantile(temperature, 0.9, na.rm = TRUE))
```